# Where to conform the API?

Tags: api, api-design

I have a software accepting a HTTP request like this (and I'm happy with that):

```
/products?page=2
/products?category=123&page=1
/product?id=123
/cart?show=table
```

Now there is a consumer third-party plug-in, I want to use, requesting like:

```
/products/page/2/category/123
```

Where is the right place to integrate this?

1. In the application self, which brings inconsistency in the API design and means that one resource is  potentially available under multiple URLs.
2. In some "proxy" layer, for example in a web server, which couples the application with the infrastructure.

Comment: Your API defines how the callers of your API should behave.  If they don't then they are out of spec.  It's as simple as that.  If you use a proxy layer to translate between the URL and the service, then you are changing the service's interface.  Now, if you used something like GraphQL to federate a standardized query against your backing services, you can get everything you need from one URL.  But those are all architectural choices you have to make.

Comment: Determine who is to design the API. Let him or her figure it out. Then comply to that API.

Comment: The client is a third party plugin I want to use. The API is already there but I can change it, extend it. As far as I can't change the plugin expectations on the API, I can either change the current API in the application, or put an additional proxy layer on the top of the application. There is no one else to let him or her figure it out. I'm asking for an advice how to deal with this.

Comment: Find (write) a new plugin that calls the API, rather than something that isn't the API?

Comment: @Caleth Writing a new plugin from scratch? The plugin is perfectly fine except for this integration issue. And it's easy to fix, I just don't know which way is the right one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Anti Corruption Layer

This is an abstract layer you add to your solution which converts one interface  to another.

It's usually used when you are upgrading legacy software. You want to split off some parts of the software into a new way of doing things, but not to have to rewrite everything.

In your case the third party is the 'new' way and your api is the legacy way.

Make a completely new API which can be called the new way and calls your API to get the results.

That way your API doesn't change, so you don't risk introducing bugs in already working systems.

To clarify you would create a completely new website

```
client -> http://newapi.com/products/page/2 
http://newapi.com/products/page/2 -> http://oldapi.com/products?page=2
http://oldapi.com/products?page=2 -> database
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was up to. There's still the question where to put this. Your answer (if I understand it correctly) is suggesting to put it outside the application itself to keep the old API. To talk a bit less abstract I image this as a new controller accepting the new API while the old one is untouched. There's still the possibility open to put the anti-corruption layer out of the app completely, for example as a routing directive to the web server. Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: yeah, move it out to a completely separate app. you don;t want to have the two together

Comment: Great, so I guess a small URL translating component on the top of the apllication, somewhere in the infrastructure, would be just fine in this case. Thank you!